# Reusing same variable for custom input in angular

Tags: angular, forms, input

I have two custom input as shown below:

```
<custom-input [name]="'lastName'" [customErrorMessage]="errorMessage" (valueChange)="lastNameChange($event)">
</custom-input>
<custom-input [name]="'firstName'" [customErrorMessage]="errorMessage" (valueChange)="firstNameChange($event)">
</custom-input>
```

As you can see I'm using the same variable `errorMessage` for both first name and last name.
It works fine i.e when I change first name only the error for first name comes and similarly for the last name. Although it is pointing to the same variable it seems to work fine.
Is there any case where this will not work?
Here is the code for custom-input component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.scss'],
  providers: [MyService]
})


export class InputComponent extends FormComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, AfterViewChecked, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

     @Input() customErrorMessage;
}
```

Comment: Please show custom-input component code

Comment: I supouse customErrorMessage is a string -no a function or a service or  a some similar- So, your components are independent: each one has his owns variables. I don't see how this will not work else if is an object, and the object is showed depending a propertie of the own object

Comment: Whats the worry here? Sharing data between components is a common use case. I don't see anything wrong with the concept.

Comment: @Eliseo Yes it is a string but it's not defined in the component place for custom input. It defined in the current component. I guess it was confusing to have same name `customErrorMessage`, I renamed `errorMessage`.